Linking warning whenever using apt
Firstly, I'm using the Debian WSL, so if that means I'm posting in the wrong place please let me know!
Recently, every time I use apt to install something, I get this message at the end:
ldconfig: Can't link /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libnvoptix_loader.so.1 to libnvoptix.so.1

It doesn't stop the installation, nor does it seem to have any adverse effects, but I'd quite like to track down the source of this problem and fix it if I can.
What might be the cause of this?

What is the output of ls -l /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libnvoptix*?

@jesse_b I'm having the same issue and the output of that is -r-xr-xr-x 1 root root 72664 Jul 10 23:29 /usr/lib/wsl/lib/libnvoptix.so.1 for me
